# What is a quick way to solve this problem: $p(x)=6x^3+3x^2-3x+8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to solve this problem make a plot. My question is, is there another quick way to solve this problem?.

> Find the correct end behavior diagram for the given polynomial function $p(x)=6x^3+3x^2-3x+8$
>
> a) rises to the left, rises to the right
>
> b) falls to the left, falls to the right
>
> c) falls to the left, rises to teh right
>
> d) rises to the left, falls to the right

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 6x^3+3x^2-3x+8 = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 6x^3 = \infty$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} 6x^3+3x^2-3x+8 = \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} 6x^3 = -\infty$$

Comment: Following the limit procedure it is very easy to say that it will rise towards right and fall towards the left....